# How javascript prototypical inheritance works for the Array, function

Tags: javascript, oop

I need to understand how the `Array` object gets a reference to `Object`.

For example, when I create `var arr = [];` it has `Array.prototype` ---> `Object.prototype` ---> `null`.

I want to achieve above for the example below:

Suppose I have a function `xyz()`, where `xyz.prototype.somefunction = function() { }`.

I have another function `abc()`, where `abc.prototype.anotherfunction = function() { }`.

When I create an object of `abc()` — as in `var obj = new abc()` — I want it to have a prototype chain like `obj` ---> `abc.prototype` ---> `xyz.prototype` ---> `object.prototype` ---> `null`.

Please suggest the best way to do this.

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf(abc.prototype, xyz.prototype);`

Comment: Please use backticks to format code properly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Or is this some kind of academic learning exercise?

Comment: Its for some learning purpose only. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @torazaburo is it possible when i create an object of abc same time its does what mentioned above. Right now i need to add the Object.setPrototyeof() se

Answer (score 1):

```
function xyz() {}
function abc() {}
var p = new xyz();
abc.prototype = p;

var o = new abc();
o.__proto__ === p // true
o.__proto__.__proto__ === xyz.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null // true
```

Or:

```
function xyz() {}
function abc() {}
var p = Object.create(xyz.prototype);
abc.prototype = p;    

var o = new abc();
o.__proto__ === p // true
o.__proto__.__proto__ === xyz.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null // true
```

Or:

```
class xyz {}
class abc extends xyz {}

var o = new abc();
o.__proto__.__proto__ === xyz.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null // true
```

Or:

```
function xyz () {}
const abc = {
    __proto__: Object.create(xyz.prototype)
}

abc.__proto__.__proto__ === xyz.prototype // true
abc.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
abc.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null // true
```

Or:

```
function xyz () {}
function abc() {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(abc.prototype, xyz.prototype);

var o = new abc();
o.__proto__.__proto__ === xyz.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
o.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null // true
```

Comment: The one with `const abc = {` isn't declaring a function like the rest.

Comment: Great. This what i was looking for .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do prototypical inheritance:

`abc.prototype = new xyz();`

now, when you create a new object, it will follow the chain you desire.